# Compare date in javascript with (d M Y) format

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json

Here is my code

```
var jsondata = eval('('+data+')');           
 for(var i=0; i<jsondata.length; i++)
 {//alert(<?php echo date('d M Y')?>);
    if(jsondata[i]['date'] < '<?php echo date('d M Y')?>'){
        var row = $("<tr id='module_tr_defaulter' >");
    }
 }
```

Here `jsondata[i]['date']` have date in d M Y format,
How i compare the json date to php current date.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Show your `jsondata`. what problem you are facing?

Comment: You should convert all your dates to javascript `Date`  objects; these are easy to compare and manipulate. However, you will likely run into problems with that if you use the `d M Y` format.

Comment: However, if i able to change jsondata[i]['date'] date format to Y-m-d, then its working.

Answer (score 0):

You cant compare json date date directly without conversion into specific date format.

```
var curDate ='<?php echo date('d M Y') ?>';
```

// compare curDate with your json date like below

```
 if(Date.parse("29 May 2015") < Date.parse(curDate)) { // your code }
```